# Login encrypton don't match DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make a register form for users.. they have a DB called Deparment, within table name users..
DB Deparment holds varius columns, including "mail" "password", they use ftp acounts, and mail acounts to read from users table of Deparment DB.

They created user's direct into MySQL using:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('user1@companyname.com', ENCRYPT('UserPassHere'));
```

Until there everything works...  "user1@companyname.com" with his password >> "UserPassHere".. can log into mail and ftp, with the same pass and username.

I'm trying to created that login form but not luck.. here is what i have been tryed in form_validator.php :

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '".ENCRYPT($_POST['password']))";
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '".MYSQLENCRYPT($_POST['password']))";
```

if I use md5 or crypt, data get inset into DB but MAIL and FTP can read the password..

I have not idea how to make password match their ENCRYPT deal..?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's [`ENCRYPT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) function is equivalent to the `crypt()` function in many other languages (e.g, [PHP](http://php.net/crypt), [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html), [python](http://docs.python.org/library/crypt.html)). The exact results of a given call to `crypt()` may be unpredictable, based on the implementation, as the salt can be chosen randomly. To give reproducible results (e.g, to check a password), pass the current password hash as the second argument to the function.

In the future, please urge your coworkers to use secure password storage schemes. Here's one such: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: It must be my inner 13-year old, but I chuckle every time I see mention of `phpass`. Such an unfortunately named project.

Comment: @duskwuff ... MySQL's ENCRYPT() function..?.. they allready had made that way.. in order to implement (insert) other type of encryption (like md5).. have they to change conf. files?... If yes.. what do I tell them?.. thanks for any help.

Comment: Wait, I was thinking of `PASSWORD()`, not `ENCRYPT()`. Updated answer accordingly!

Comment: @duskwuff thanks.. so back to the point, how do I suppose to make a register form that store a password matching their current configuration... remember that INSERT ENCRYPT does not work at all... How do I INSERT a password that get into Table, matching their conf..?.. thanks for all your help

Comment: Forget to said that they will not let me change their configuration files..  and if I use > INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '".CRYPT($_POST['password']))";   does insert values into tbale, but mail or ftp cant read then back, so user cant login... Knowing that md5, crypt insertion.. before ($_POST['password'])) works, but users cant login... I know they have been used (in MySQL terminal ) > INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '".ENCRYPT($_POST['password']))", and these users CAN login without any problem...?